# Solve $(A(x).\nabla)u+cu=0$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, ds.dynamical-systems

ِDoes the equation
$y\partial_x u(x,y)-x\partial_y u(x,y)+cu=0$
have complex-valued  compact-supported or vanishing-at-infinity $C^1$ solution defined on the whole plane without any singularity? Here $c$ is a complex number.
I have used the method of characteristics but the solution is
$u(x,y)=g(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})exp(-c arctg(y/x))$
where g is a given function. But this solution has singularity at x=0.
More generally, a similar question for the equation
$(A(x).\nabla)u+cu=0$
where $A(x)$ is a real vector field over $R^n$ and $c$ is a complex number. Is there a  complex-valued  compact-supported or vanishing-at-infinity $C^1$ solution on whole $R^n$?

Comment: Did you also want non-trivial? Since $u\equiv 0$is a solution.

Comment: In any case, your equation can be written in polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$ as $$ \partial_\theta u + c u = 0 $$ and the existence of non-singular solution boils down to asking whether the equation $g' = -c g$ has a $2\pi$ periodic solution.

Comment: Since you mentioned the similar equation and method of characteristics: it depends on the geometry of the integral curves of $A$. If $A$ has closed curves then there will be at most a discrete, countable set of $c$ that will work. OTOH, if all integral curves of $A$ are unbounded, then the only compactly supported solution will be the 0 solution.

Comment: @ Willie Thanks for useful comments.